# Can't login Facebook with export apk file

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-access-token

I use Facebook SDK into my app. 
When I build directly from my PC to phone or get apk file from bin folder in project, Facebook can login normally.

But when I export apk file, I installed again to my phone. Facebook can't login and always show "Invalid access token" message.

Please help me. Thanks so much.

Comment: which keystore you are using while exporting app?

Comment: You need to register your new key with facebook, the keystore you use to export changes the key.

Comment: I used this command: keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64. And password is android. I used this key to add into Facebook.  Is something wrong??? Please help.

Comment: I find solution, thanks all

Comment: @yagi_chan : i am also getting the same issue in my application. when i am directly running my application from eclipse, Facebook SSO is working fine, but when i am generating apk, then facebook SSO is not working. can you please help me to resolve this problem in my application. Thankx in Advance.. :)

Comment: Hi, it's up to your keystore, when you debug, it used android debug keystore by command: keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64. But when build apk, you should use keystore that you built apk, and get key by command: keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64.